# numeric format strings #,#0.00 vs #,0.00

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I tried to figure out the basics of these [numeric string formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings). So I think I understand the basics but there is one thing I'm not sure about

So, for example

```
#,##0.00
```

It turns out that it produces identical results as

```
#,#0.00
```

or

```
#,0.00
#,#########0.00
```

So my question is, why are people using the `#,##` so often (I see it a lot when googling)

Maybe I missed something.

You can try it out yourself [here](https://try.dot.net/) and put the following inside that main function

```
 double value = 1234.67890;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,0.00"));
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#0.00"));
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0.00"));
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,########0.00"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably because Microsoft uses the same format specifier in their documentation, including the page you linked.  It's not too hard to figure out why; `#,##0.00` more clearly states the programmer's intent: three-digit groups separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens?

The following function is called:

```
public string ToString(string? format)
{
    return Number.FormatDouble(m_value, format, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

It is important to realize that the format **is used to format the string**, but your formats happen to give the same result.

#### Examples:

```
value.ToString("#,#")      // 1,235
value.ToString("0,0")      // 1,235
value.ToString("#")        // 1235
value.ToString("0")        // 1235
value.ToString("#.#"))     // 1234.7
value.ToString("#.##")     // 1234.68
value.ToString("#.###")    // 1234.679
value.ToString("#.#####")  // 1234.6789
value.ToString("#.######") // =  value.ToString("#.#######") = 1234.6789
```

We see that

- it doesn't matter whether you put `#`, `0`, or any other digit for that matter
- One occurrence means: any arbitrary large number

```
  double value = 123467890;
  Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#")); // Prints the full number
```

- `,` and `.` however, are treated different for double
- After a dot or comma, it will only show the amount of character that are provided (or less: as for `#.######`).

At this point it's clear that it has to do with the programmer's intent. If you want to display the number as `1,234.68` or `1234.67890`, you would format it as

```
"#,###.##"   or "#,#.##"  // 1,234.68
"####.#####" or "#.#####" // 1234.67890
```